# Engine Bearings Damage in Radial Engines

Tags: piston-engine, engine-design, aircraft-limitations

Studying the P47's dive performance in DCS, I noticed how it's easy to damage the engine bearings if you windmill the prop at high speed.
Doing some research, I discovered that all radial engines are prone to this type of damage.

> If,  because  of  insufficient  gas  load  (manifold  pressure),  the  propeller  is  allowed  to  drive the engine, the  resultant force on the crankshaft is applied  to  the opposite side of  the crankpin, where the oil supply is not optimised, and may quickly damage the bearing.    This damage  worsens  over time and  eventually  the bearing will  fail.  Failure  may occur several hours after  the  initiating event,  and therefore a  pilot may inadvertently damage the  bearing without seeing any immediate symptoms  requiring maintenance intervention.   The  engine is designed  to cope with some reverse loading  for brief periods,  for example  when  the propeller  is driven at  lower airspeed when landing, but  critical damage may occur quickly at higher speeds
>
> Source: AAIB Bulletin: 10/2021 / G-INVN / AAIB-26839 ([PDF](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/612f8f04d3bf7f0387e8aa37/Hawker_Sea_Fury_T_Mk.20_G-INVN_10-21.pdf))

I can't understand at 100%  why V, Inline , boxer ecc.. engines don't suffer of this problem too.
Probably the reason is due the load distribution that's completely different, but not sure.

[image]

Other source:
https://forums.eagle.ru/topic/260841-engine-bearings-and-how-you-can-keep-them-happy/

Comment: You are talking about the crankshaft thrust bearings, not the main journal bearings no?

Comment: Why do you say non-radials don't suffer the same? Share your research please.

Comment: I think that the damage is shared between both bearings; but probably the more damaged are the thrust bearing. I am going to share the links of where I found this information; one of those it's a report of a Sea Fury Crash. Let me know if you need more infos. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you read the second link carefully, it describes everything quite precisely, so I'm not sure why you're posting this question.The master rod is getting loaded on the opposite side of the oil feed hole when the prop is back driving, and the pressure on that side is insufficient to keep the metal apart under high backdriving loads,which are all concentrated on just two master rod bearings for all cylinders.Other engines don't suffer from this because those loads are distributed across individual connecting rods and the pressures trying to squeeze out the oil at the rod big end are much lower.

Comment: I agree with @John but I'm not convinced by the explanation in the article, as this reverse load also occurs when the engine is decelerated, not only when windmilling.

Comment: As I specified in the post, is clear that the loads are distributed in a completely different way in normals engine configurations; but there should be some damage related to windmilling also in them, but in a engine equipped with a constant speed propeller I never heard of that. (except going beyond engine RPM limit)

Comment: I think I understand the concept of that is going on.The master rod's bearing is being pushed on by the articulating rods in sequence, which tends to make them push on the same point on the crank pin, so if you clock the oil hole in the crank pin at spot X, that spot is always facing the articulating rod of the cylinder being fired as they go around, and therefore when back driving, the crank pin is now pushing on the master rod bearing at a point 180 deg away opposite the crank pin's oil hole.Normally the loads have declined where this doesn't matter, except in an extreme high speed windmill.

Comment: This all could be condensed into an answer, but oil deprivation seems to be key.  A straight crankshaft may have oil splashing equally on all sides, whereas the radial is famous for oil tending towards the bottom.  I'm also seeing all pistons turning one wheel on the radial.  With the inline, the heavy crankshaft can be absorbing differences in piston pressure better.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies! They were very helpful to understand completely the differences. The last comment of Robert completed the pieces that I was missing!! Thanks again! Airplanes are cool